# Node crashing often on my MacBook, but I don't know what is using node

Tags: mac

How do I troubleshoot this? The crashed process pop-up appears every now and then.

It looks like it's a process that immediately crashes, so doesn't appear in the process list.

```
Process:               node [8824]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node
Identifier:            node
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        plugin_host [8802]
Responsible:           node [8824]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-04-24 15:28:55.712 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.4 
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0

Time Awake Since Boot: 33000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100fb808f +node (???) <C0E2FA16-9C1B-3805-9967-EB7543CD9520> /usr/local/bin/node
       0x10dbad000 -        0x10dc176ef  dyld (655.1.1) <F217F7F8-A795-3109-B77F-B1E2277F3E3B> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Answer (score 0):

You troubleshoot by looking at the specific error causing the crash, which in this case is:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
```

And a quick Google of `node icu4c macos` returns a lot of messages about this, including this post from [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780207/installing-node-with-brew-fails-on-mac-os-sierra) with numerous solutions either reinstalling or upgrading node and the lib in question, icu4c.